# The mathematical quiz

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

There are 4 equations. What should I put in place of the `?` in the last one?

```
1 + 4 = 5
5 + 3 = 11
7 * 7 = 61
10 - 1 = ?
```

Comment: Is this an original question? If not, you should put the source in your puzzle text just to give due credit to its original author.

Comment: My mother-in-law is author. How should I credit her?

Comment: @asiniy Are you sure the second equation is not 5+3=10?

Comment: @asiniy You already did. Just by stating who's the author is crediting him/her.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

> It looks to me like a simple octal calculation (i.e. base-8), assuming that there was an error on the second line. If this is the case then the answer is 7.

Comment: so you mean calculate in decimal then convert to Octal/Base 8?

Comment: @ALinuxLover No, I mean all the numbers are Base 8.

Comment: oh ok makes more sense heh

Answer (score 4):

I guess the answer provided by @rhsquared is correct provided the OP corrects the question. But a more far fetched answer by assumption is

> **9 = 10-1 = 49 - (8*5)**        - From Normal Maths
>  **10-1 = (7*7) - [(1+4)*(5+3)]**  - Rearrangement 
>   **10-1 = 61 - [5*8]**            -Substitution from above rules
>  **10-1 = 61 - 55= 6.**            -Substitution from above rules & From Normal Maths

Answer (score 4):

I think that one possible answer to the equations can be:

> **(Given data) + (3 * n * n)** in which the n represents the iteration number, starting by 0.
>  **(1 + 4) + (3 * 0 * 0) = 5 + 0 = 5** -> Iteration 0
>  **(5 + 3) + (3 * 1 * 1) = 8 + 3 = 11** -> Iteration 1
>  **(7 * 7) + (3 * 2 * 2) = 49 + 12 = 61** -> Iteration 2
>  **(10 - 1) + (3 * 3 * 3) = 9 + 27 = 36** -> Iteration 3
>  Then, the answer is 36.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer using the previous answer and 2 to the power of the line index:

> 1 + 4 = 5
> 5 + 3 = 11 = 8 + (5-2^1)
> 7 * 7 = 61 = 49 + (11+5-2^2)
> 10 - 1 = 78 = 9 + (61+11+5-2^3)

Comment: But what if the last sum is alternating, where $10 - 1 = 38 = 9 + (61 - 11 + 5 - 2^3)\,?$

Comment: @user477343 an infinite number of solutions exist, and therefore an infinite number of "what ifs". The simplest solutions are preferred.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you might be right then. Perhaps the pattern was *subtracting* by $2^n$ instead of $2^n$ being the last summand of an alternating sum. My answer above was an entirely new pattern that I found, so maybe there *are* infinitely many patterns...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> $10 - 1 = 23$

This is because,

> The first prime after $(1 + 4) - 1 = 4$ is $5$. Notice that *first* corresponds to $1 = 2^0$. $\quad\qquad$
> The second prime after $(5 + 3) - 3 = 5$ is $11$. Notice that *second* corresponds to $2 = 2^1$. $\quad$
> The fourth prime after $(7\times 7) - 5 = 44$ is $61$. Notice that *fourth* corresponds to $4 = 2^2$.

Now, we do as follows:

> We look at the fourth expression, namely ($10 - 1$), and then we subtract this by the next odd number from $5$, namely $7$, to make $$(10 - 1) - 7 = 2.$$ And now since $2^3 = 8$, we find the $8^\text{th}$ prime number after $2$, which is $23$. $$\therefore 10 - 1 = 23$$